# ggplot2: draw lines connecting observations in each group in faceted boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
set.seed(20210714)
dd <- data.frame(Method = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 60), Pattern = as.factor(rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), times = 30)), X1 = runif(180), Complexity = rep(c("High", "Low"), times = 90), nsim = rep(rep(1:10, times = 9), each = 2))
```

I want to get boxplots of X1 for each method and across the three patterns and within each complexity. I use the following plot:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x = Pattern, y = X1, fill = Method)) +
    facet_grid(~Complexity) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=1))
```

which gives me the attached figure:

[image]

Fabulous. However, each observation for method A, B and C are on the same dataset (with indicator nsim) within 'X' (same for the cases within 'Y' and same for within 'Z') and I would like to link the observations (values of X1) between the three methods in each of the three patterns (but not link the three patterns because that would be meaningless).

Specifically, I want a plot as follows (with hand-drawn lines imagined to connect the different simulations IDS here):

[image]

So, I tried the following, however,I am getting the boxplots to no longer be bunched together for each x (and the x axes is now also messed up).

```
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(dd, aes(x = interaction(Method,Pattern), y = X1, fill = Method)) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Method), position = "identity")  +
    geom_line(aes(x = interaction(Method,Pattern), y = X1,
                group=interaction(Pattern,nsim)), 
            size = 0.15, alpha = 0.5, colour = I("#525252"))  +
  facet_grid(~Complexity) + 
    theme_light()  +
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom')  +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=1)) +
      geom_line(aes(x = interaction(Method,Pattern), 
                group=interaction(Pattern,nsim)), 
            size = 0.35, alpha = 0.5, colour = I("#525252"))  + 
    geom_point(aes(x = interaction(Method,Pattern), 
                group=interaction(Pattern,nsim)), 
               size = 0.35, alpha = 0.5, colour = I("#525252"))  +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("","X", "", "", "Y", "", "", "Z","")) + xlab("Pattern")
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

but the boxplots for each setting of Pattern gets separated (I would like them bunched together) and also the x-axes gets messed up (which I have somewhat of an inelegant fix). So, the most important thing I need resolved still  is the space between the boxplots inside each Pattern (which I would like to be smaller) than the space between boxplots of different Patterns.

How do I fix this? Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide a sketch, or clearer instructions, on exactly how you want this plot to look?

Comment: For the left-most red boxplot, there are 15000 observations, which means 50 distinct values for each `Method`/`nsim` permutation. If you want 1 red line tying together the `nsim` between various groups, which of the 50 `nsim` values in a particular group do you want to tie to the others?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, my test code was not correct, now there is only one simulation ID for each Method x Pattern combination. Thanks, @r2evans!

Comment: This is a bit challenging since your x-axis is discrete, not numeric, so you'll have to fake quite a bit.

Comment: Issue seems to be that layering a geom_line() over (or perhaps within) a set of values already serving as fill & the x-axis.    aggr<-dd %>% 
      group_by(Pattern,Complexity,Method) %>% 
      summarise(MeanX=mean(X1,na.rm=T),Method=first(Method)) ;
    aggr$Method2<-ifelse(aggr$Method=="A","X",
                         ifelse(aggr$Method=="B","Y",
                                 ifelse(aggr$Method=="C","Z",NA)));
    ggplot(dd) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(x = Pattern, y = X1, fill = (Method))) +
    facet_wrap(~Complexity)+geom_line(data=aggr,aes(Method2,MeanX,group=factor(Method)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there are better methods of doing this, but I did the following:

```
set.seed(20210714)
dd <- data.frame(Method = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 60), Pattern = rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), times = 30), X1 = runif(180), Complexity = rep(c("High", "Low"), times = 90), nsim = rep(rep(1:10, times = 9), each = 2))

library(ggplot2)

# create dummy dataframe.
dummy.df <- dd
dummy.df[nrow(dd) + 1:2,"Pattern"] <- unique(dd$Pattern)[-3]
dummy.df[nrow(dd) + 1:2,"Method"] <- "ZZZ"
dummy.df[nrow(dd) + 1:2,"Complexity"] <- c("High","Low")

dummy.df$dummy <- interaction(dummy.df$Method,dummy.df$Pattern)             


ggplot(dummy.df, aes(x = dummy, y = X1, fill = Method)) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Method)) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = dummy, y = X1,
                group=interaction(Pattern,nsim)), 
            size = 0.15, alpha = 0.5, colour = I("#525252"))  +
  facet_grid(~Complexity) + 
    theme_light()  +
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom')  +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=1)) +
      geom_line(aes(x = dummy, 
                group=interaction(Pattern,nsim)), 
            size = 0.35, alpha = 0.5, colour = I("#525252"))  + 
    geom_point(aes(x = dummy, 
                group=interaction(Pattern,nsim)), 
               size = 0.35, alpha = 0.5, colour = I("#525252"))  +
   scale_x_discrete(labels = c("","X", "", "", "", "Y", "", "", "", "Z","","")) +
    xlab("Pattern") +
    scale_fill_brewer(breaks=c("A", "B", "C"), type="qual", palette="Dark2")
```

which yields the following:

[image]

I would like the boxplots to be closer to each other, and would like some advice on how to do this, if anyone has any ideas. Perhaps the next step will be to write this up as a general function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x = Pattern, y = X1, fill = Method)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=interaction(Method,nsim)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
            size = 0.1, alpha = 0.5, colour = I("#525252"))  + 
  facet_grid(~Complexity) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=1)) +
  theme_light()
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite. The nsim across the patterns is not comparable so the lines have to stop in each of x, y, z. I have an alternative that I am putting up, but that is still a little messed up.

Comment: @user3236841 I think you may make it easier for people trying to help you by constructing a _truly minimal_ example - much easier to show and explain the logic when you can track a few points/lines, and then easier for people to verify their code. Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik, excellent point. Question edited with 10 data points in each case to hopefully allow for easier tracking of the lines.